# Pagination (Node) module html tags are broken drupal

Tags: drupal

I am using page Pagination (Node) module in drupal .In body i used full html filter.Then i used html tags(

,,etc.. ).I gave 150  words as per page.If a tag is at 145 word it is getting broken.Please give me solution

Answer (score 0):

try to use "filtered html"..and then use `<!--pagebreak-->`